# asking for password before i can access the network drive

Tags: windows-server-2003, network-share

I mapped the network drive of Server 2k3 to an XP xlient computer (join to domain),

However, whenever i access the network drive to the client computer, it always asking for a password.

What will i do to access directly the network drive.

Comment: asking for password during my first access to the network drive.

Comment: You can always edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Are the credentials you're supplying to the network drive the same as the user logged into the XP machine?

Comment: @Cole. No it has different credentials.  the credentials needed to access the network drive is the username password of Server Administrator

Comment: Why don't you just give that user access so that they don't need alternate credentials?

Comment: @MDMarra, i already permitted the user to access the network drive, still it is asking for credentials.

Comment: Then you didn't do it correctly.

Comment: what would be the right thing to do?

Comment: You may want to read up on NTFS Permissions [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2005.11.howitworksntfs.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

That's why it's asking for credentials. You can do this from the command line. It will prompt you for the username and password, and then will no longer prompt you for it afterwards.

```
net use <drive letter>: \\<servername>\<Share> /savecred /p:yes
```

Comment: is this command for server computer or client computer?.. i try this to the client computer, but its not working..

Comment: On the XP machine, what's the error you're receiving? What does your command look like?

Comment: i cant type the password, that cause discontinue of the command